# Jenkins Pipeline use parameters from one job to another between stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We Have a Jenkins pipeline with several stages (powershell).
each stage has one or more jobs to be executed.
I need to use the results of the first job and pass them to the next job at the next stage.
except the pipeline all jobs are powershell.

example:

```
node('one'){
   stage ('Get Info from DB'){
   build job: 'test1'
   }
   stage ('Do Something'){
   build job: 'test2' parameters: [string(name: 'PARAM1', value: $PARAM_FROM_test1 )]
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to retrieve the outputs of the first job test1 and use these outputs in a second job,  you can simply in the second job  use the copyArtifact class :

```
     step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'test1'])
```

This is achieved, assuming that in test1 job, you use the ArtifactArchiver class like (for instance):

```
      step([$class: "ArtifactArchiver", artifacts: "*.tgz", fingerprint: true])
```